# Logary with Logstash to Elastic Search - simple configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logary

I've been trying to set up logging for my .NET application using Logary > Logstash > ElasticSearch for nearly the entire day. I've tried every variation of the configuration I can think of and went through docs for hours to no avail.

What is wrong here?

```
 var logary = LogaryFactory.New("Logary Specs", with => with

                .Target<Logstash.Builder>("ls", conf => conf.Target
                        .Hostname("localhost")
                        .Port(1939)
                        .EventVersion(Logstash.EventVersion.One)
                        .Done())

                .Target<Debugger.Builder>("debugger")
            );
```

Here's the logstash.conf:

```
input { 
    stdin {}

    tcp {
         codec => json_lines { charset => "UTF-8" }
         host  => localhost
         port  => 1939
         type  => "app"
     }
}

output {

   stdout {}
   elasticsearch {
      host => localhost
      protocol => "http"
   }
}
```

I've tried without output.elasticsearch.protocol as with host => "0.0.0.0" like in docs, and every combination in between.

I have ES up on 9200 and Kibana loaded up and I can see logs show up through stdin/stdout but not from my application logs using Logary. It's also verified that the Logary debugger target works.

What's wrong with my pipeline here?

Logstash 1.4.2

ES 1.3.4

Comment: Can you see the logs from stdin in Kibana?

Comment: Are you using the pre-release version of Logary? It's probably even better at this point as it has much better internal logging and structure.

Comment: What logs are you getting from Logary?

Comment: ...................from inside Logary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some components to debug it.

I wrote a sample program for you to use to debug it; this is the simplest possible thing that can work:

```
open System

open Logary
open Logary.Configuration
open Logary.Targets

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
  use logary =
    withLogary' "logstash-sample" (
      withTargets [
        Logstash.create (Logstash.LogstashConf.Create "10.0.0.120") "logstash"
        Debugger.create Debugger.empty "debugger"
      ] >>
      withRules [
        Rule.createForTarget "logstash"
        Rule.createForTarget "debugger"
      ] >>
      withInternalTargets Verbose [
        Debugger.create (Debugger.empty) "console"
      ]
    )

  let logger = logary.GetLogger "logstash-sample"
  Logger.debug logger "Hello World"

  Console.ReadKey true |> ignore
  0
```

Here's its expected Debugger output (not console).

```
'logstash_sample.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'logstash_sample.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'Y:\dev\ip\_scratch\logstash-sample\bin\Debug\logstash_sample.exe', Symbols loaded.
'logstash_sample.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'Y:\dev\ip\_scratch\logstash-sample\bin\Debug\Logary.dll', Symbols loaded.
'logstash_sample.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'Y:\dev\ip\_scratch\logstash-sample\bin\Debug\NodaTime.dll'
'logstash_sample.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\FSharp.Core\v4.0_4.3.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\FSharp.Core.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'logstash_sample.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'logstash_sample.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'logstash_sample.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'logstash_sample.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'Y:\dev\ip\_scratch\logstash-sample\bin\Debug\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'
'logstash_sample.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'Y:\dev\ip\_scratch\logstash-sample\bin\Debug\Intelliplan.JsonNet.dll'
'logstash_sample.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'Y:\dev\ip\_scratch\logstash-sample\bin\Debug\Intelliplan.JsonNet.NodaTime.dll'
'logstash_sample.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'Y:\dev\ip\_scratch\logstash-sample\bin\Debug\FSharp.Actor.dll'
'logstash_sample.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
D 2014-10-18T10:25:42.4192736+00:00: supervisor status: Running [Logary.Registry.runRegistry]
I 2014-10-18T10:25:42.4192736+00:00: initing logstash target, connecting to 10.0.0.120:1936... [Logary.Targets.Logstash.logstashLoop]
D 2014-10-18T10:25:42.4383230+00:00: scheduler status: Running [Logary.Registry.runRegistry]
D 2014-10-18T10:25:42.4473276+00:00: registry status: Running [Logary.Registry.runRegistry]
D 2014-10-18T10:25:42.4977127+00:00: will poll metrics every 0:00:00:00.5 [Logary.Registry.registry]
D 2014-10-18T10:25:42.5335455+00:00: Hello World [logstash-sample]
I 2014-10-18T10:25:42.5515369+00:00: initing logstash target, connected [Logary.Targets.Logstash.logstashLoop]
'logstash_sample.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'logstash_sample.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'logstash_sample.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'logstash_sample.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'logstash_sample.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
D 2014-10-18T10:25:42.7268749+00:00: polling metrics [Logary.Registry.registry]
D 2014-10-18T10:25:42.8571421+00:00: send-recv stream not open, opening [Logary.Targets.Logstash.logstashLoop]
I 2014-10-18T10:25:43.1096339+00:00: start shutdown [Logary.Configuration.Config.shutdown]
I 2014-10-18T10:25:43.1186538+00:00: flush start [Logary.Registry.registry]
I 2014-10-18T10:25:43.1667422+00:00: flush Ack [Logary.Registry.registry]
I 2014-10-18T10:25:43.1787861+00:00: shutdown metrics polling [Logary.Registry.registry]
I 2014-10-18T10:25:43.1798152+00:00: shutdown schedules [Logary.Registry.registry]
I 2014-10-18T10:25:43.1798152+00:00: shutdown targets [Logary.Registry.registry]
I 2014-10-18T10:25:43.2018104+00:00: shutdown Ack [Logary.Registry.registry]
I 2014-10-18T10:25:43.2018104+00:00: shutting down immediately [Logary.Registry.registry]
I 2014-10-18T10:25:43.2118258+00:00: stop shutdown [Logary.Configuration.Config.shutdown]
The program '[4820] logstash_sample.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

This code is here:

https://github.com/logary/logary/commit/0dca450677dc1ca691292d379a734c7051743c1c

You can do `Install-Package Intelliplan.Logary -Pre` and then copy over the `Logary.dll`-dll file. Ensure you have the same output.

If you can successfully connect to logstash as per the output above, you can verify that it's receiving the events or failing by printing to its log;

```
tail -f /var/log/logstash/logstash-agent.log
```

Comment: I released alpha.7 with the code changes, so you don't need to compile it yourself.

Comment: do you have a c# version for this I'm not sure how Im supposed to plug this into my MVC application

Comment: Ok it started working. not really sure if it was the alpha.7 release (thank you) or my own mistake. Basically I wanted to install logstash as a windows service so I used NSSM to create a window service based off a "run.bat" containing "logstash agent -f logstash.conf". The generated service looks good but doesnt work. Running logstash normally by double clicking that same run.bat worked. Also , the release could have played a part. Thanks anyways!

Comment: You config was alright for C# (as you noticed ;)) - I wanted to give you a minimal stand-alone app to test with. Glad it worked out!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you can try. First double check whether your elasticsearch cluster is actually green/yellow. I wasted a good few hours once because I had specified a higher number of replicas in the elasticsearch index template I configured.

Of course check both the elasticsearch and logstash logs for any errors.

Next, try using

`elasticsearch_http {
  host => "localhost"
}`

This uses the http protocol rather than the internal protocol and frees you having to have the exact same elastic search version as was bundled with logstash.

Finally, if that doesn't work, I recommend poking around in the logstash directory and modifying the ruby script that implements the plugin. It's nice when it works but the logging is somewhat lacking when it doesn't; which is easily fixed with some log statements.

Comment: thanks but unfortunately didnt work. not sure what you mean about checking whether my elasticsearch cluster is green/yellow. I'm using default configuration.

Comment: @parliament: Use the `/_cluster/health` REST endpoint. See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-health.html.

Comment: @JillesvanGurp: The elasticsearch_http output is being deprecated in favor of elasticsearch with `protocol => "http"` set. See https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash/issues/1757.